# Jira automation smart values of github integration

Tags: github, automation, jira

I have the Github integration for Jira and want to set up some Jira automations integrating with Github API. What I'm looking for specifically is the possibility to get hold of either the Github PR id (or the full PR link) from the "smart values" library within Jira.

I've tried `issue.property[development].pr` but it doesn't return anything.

Any ideas if the PR info is exposed as [smart values](https://docs.automationforjira.com/reference/smart-values.html) in Jira at all?

Comment: (1) According to [JIRA admin docu](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/integrating-with-development-tools-776636216.html) there are some limitations on the supported versions: Which JIRA version are you using?
(2) Do I understand you correctly that you initiate the pull request with Github? (There are indeed customers, where the PR has to be initiated in JIRA).

Comment: Yes, the PR is initiated with Github. We're running Jira version v8.3.2

Answer (score 3):

All the GitHub related data would be present in the [webhookData](https://docs.automationforjira.com/reference/smart-values.html#webhookdata) smart value, which will contain the data sent by GitHub's webhook.

So to access the PR's URL, you can use `webhookData.pull_request.html_url` as shown in the screenshot below. Similarly, you can access any other field sent by GitHub's webhook payload via `webhookData`.

[image]

**Credits**: The complete steps on integrating Jira and GitHub using Automation for Jira is provided in **Simeon Ross**'s [article](https://blog.codebarrel.io/how-to-integrate-jira-and-github-using-automation-for-jira-238d19a3be68).

The `issue` smart value would have all the data associated with a JIRA issue. You can create custom fields and set them to the issue when the GitHub data is receiver by the webhook. So if you have added any GitHub data to your issue, you can find the json representation of the issue and try finding out the right smart value with `customField.value`. You can try accessing the custom fields by following the steps in [here](https://docs.automationforjira.com/issues/find-the-correct-smart-value-for-fields-in-jira.html#smart-values-for-fields).

Comment: Did this help you @mar-schmidt ?

Comment: Unfortionatly no. The thing is that Im not looking for how to process incoming webhook. Im trying to access the issue PR id (exist in the jira issue) for an outgoing webhook...

Comment: @mar-schmidt I have updated my answer with additional info which you can try out. Let me know if that helps.